# Как поменять местами элементы при перетаскивании?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

Взял пример [portlets](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets) из официальной документации jQuery. Возникла необходимость обмена элементов, т.е. перетаскиваемого и на который наводят. В примере при перетаскивании элемент просто вставляется в столбец. Как это можно реализовать?

Хочу, чтобы при перетаскивании элемента он не просто вставлялся в столбец, а менялся местами с элементом, на который наведена мышь.

Пример из документации:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
  });

  $(".portlet")
    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
    .find(".portlet-header")
    .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

  $(".portlet-toggle").on("click", function() {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.portlet {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.portlet-header {
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.portlet-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.portlet-content {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.portlet-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Каких элементов? Какой пример? Объясните как можно подробнее чего Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: обновил пост с примером

Comment: Стало, конечно, получше, но все равно непонятно. Ваш код — это неполный [пример из документации](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets). Полный пример (на оф. сайте) у Вас работает? Что мешает скопировать целиком?

Comment: Полный код работает более чем хорошо. Проблема не в его неработоспособности, а в логике работы. При перетаскивании он просто вставляет в столбец перетаскиваемый элемент, что-то типа swappable библиотеки, которую находил на просторах интернета, но не смог ее заставить работать